# Writing an iterator for a 2D array

Tags: arrays, scala, iterator

I am trying to write an iterator for a 2D array. The following is what I have come up with.

```
  def rowsTest() {
    val array = Array(
      Array(9, 11, 4, 89),
      Array(7, 62, 34, 2),
      Array(3, 4, 5, 12),
      Array(13, 4, 5, 12),
      Array(3, 24, 5, 12),
      Array(3, 4, 35, 12)
    )
    def rows: Iterator[Iterator[Int]] = {
      new Iterator[Iterator[Int]] {
        private var rowIndex = 0

        def hasNext: Boolean = rowIndex < 6

        def next: Iterator[Int] = {
          val rowIterator = new Iterator[Int] {
            private var columnIndex = 0

            def next: Int = {
              val p = array(columnIndex)(rowIndex)
              columnIndex += 1
              println("ColIndex = "+ columnIndex.toString)
              p
            }

            def hasNext: Boolean = columnIndex < 4
          }
          rowIndex += 1
          println("RowIndex = "+ rowIndex.toString)
          rowIterator
        }
      }
    }
    for(row <- rows; elem <- row)
      println(elem)
  }
```

The above code when run skips the first row, and also gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when all elements have been printed. Can you help me figure out where I've gone wrong?

Thank you,
Siddharth Raina.

Answer (score 5):

How about the following code?

```
val array = Array(Array(1,2,3),Array(4,5,6),Array(7,8,9))
array.view.flatten.iterator
```

It works, as tested in REPL. Though I don't know if I achieve what I intended with "view". Any comments are welcome.

**Edit**

I forgot the author wanted a nested iterator.

```
array.iterator.map(_.iterator)
```

This certainly works without the "view" and without overhead.

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell from your code what you actually want to do.

If you want traverse your array with iterators of iterators, there's already an easy way to do it:

```
val a2d = Array.tabulate(4,4)((i,j)=>4*i+j)
a2d.iterator.map(_.iterator)
```

And if you decide you want a single iterator, you can do that too:

```
a2d.iterator.flatMap(_.iterator)
```

If you want to traverse *columns* even though the array is in row-major order, then you have a little more work to do (which I think is what you were trying to do, but you mixed up your array indices, and maybe some other things):

```
def iterateColumns(aai: Array[Array[Int]]) = new Iterator[Iterator[Int]] {
  private[this] var j = -1
  private[this] val shortest = if (aai.length==0) 0 else aai.map(_.length).min
  def hasNext = j+1 < shortest
  def next = {
    j += 1
    new Iterator[Int] {
      private[this] var i = -1
      def hasNext = i+1 < aai.length
      def next = {
        i += 1
        aai(i)(j)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can

```
scala> for (row <- a2d.iterator.map(_.iterator)) println(row.mkString(" "))
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15

scala> for (col <- iterateColumns(a2d)) println(col.mkString(" "))
0 4 8 12
1 5 9 13
2 6 10 14
3 7 11 15
```

(You also ought to be able to do `a2d.view.transpose.iterator.map(_.iterator)` to avoid making a copy, but unfortunately it doesn't look like this works the way you'd hope in 2.8.1.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it handmade in an imperative style:

```
  def rowsTest() {
    val array = Array(
      Array(9, 11, 4, 89),
      Array(7, 62, 34, 2),
      Array(3, 4, 5, 12),
      Array(13, 4, 5, 12),
      Array(3, 24, 5, 12),
      Array(3, 4, 35, 12)
    )
    def rows: Iterator[Iterator[Int]] = {
      new Iterator[Iterator[Int]] {
        private var rowIndex = 0
        def hasNext: Boolean = rowIndex < 6
        def next: Iterator[Int] = {
          // fix row index for inner iterator
          val rowIdx = rowIndex
          val rowIterator = new Iterator[Int] {
            private var columnIndex = 0
            def next: Int = {
              // swap indices!!!
              val p = array(rowIdx)(columnIndex)
              columnIndex += 1
              println("ColIndex = " + columnIndex.toString)
              p
            }
            def hasNext: Boolean = columnIndex < 4
          }
          rowIndex += 1
          println("RowIndex = " + rowIndex.toString)
          rowIterator
        }
      }
    }
    for (row <- rows; elem <- row)
      println(elem)
  }
```

but the

```
val rows: Iterator[Iterator[Int]] = array.iterator.map(_.iterator)
```

of ziggystar is still better because its work with non rectangular 2D-arrays too and is more consice and "scalaish".